# Prove that for all positive integers $n$, the fraction $\frac{21n + 4}{14n + 3}$ is irreducible.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm beginning number theory and reading Number Theory Structure, Examples, and Problems. And had problems understanding the solution.

Prove that for all positive integers $n$, the fraction

$$\frac{21n + 4}{14n + 3}$$ is irreducible.

Solution:

Indeed, from the equality

$$2(21n+4) - 3(14n+3)= -1$$

it follows  that $21n + 4$  and $14n+3$ have no common divisor except for $1$, hence the conclusion.

What is the importance of the subtraction equality?

Comment: Hint $\ d\mid a,b\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid ja+kb\,$ when $\,j,k\,$ are integers. If the linear combination $=\color{#c00}{\bf 1}$ then this implies that $\,a,b\,$ are coprime since every common divisor $\,d\,$ divides $\color{#c00}{\bf 1}\ $

Comment: This is the first ever question asked for the INTERNATIONAL MATHEMATICS OLYMPIAD

Answer (score 1):

$$3(14n+3)-2(21n+4) = 1$$
    says that the gcd of Numerator and Denominator is $1$.
    That is the numbers are always coprime, independent of $n$.
    Therefore the fraction is irreducible.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that some positive integer $k$ divides both $21n+4$ and $14n+3$. What can you conclude from the subtraction inequality? What must $k$ divide?

Comment: If 21n + 4 and 14n + 3 is divisble by an integer k. Then the subtraction equality will be true????

Comment: The subtraction equality is always true. But it allows you to conclude that if $k$ divides $21n+4$ and $14n+3$, then it must divide something else.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has a good history. First problem of first IMO. Solution:

Using Euclidean algorithm:

$$21n+4=(14n+3)\times 1+7n+1$$

$$14n+3=(7n+1)\times2+1\implies (21n+4,14n+3)=1$$

So there is nothing to cancel between $21n+4$ and $14n+3$ and hence the given fraction is irreducible.